# Pass updated data to home activity without refreshing any activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here I have 3 activity and `ActivityA` contain `textView` which show username , `ActivityB` contain only button to redirect `ActivityC`, `ActivityC` Contain `EditText`  and save button.

[image]

Now i want to change updated text from `ActivityC` to direct  `ActivityA` when save button clicked without refreshing any Activity than what i have to do? can you please suggest simple way.

I have a same requirement in complex project, i need to save user location at server side using api call and show updated data in `ActivityA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to use LocalBroadcastManager.
The code will be as follows.

```
//ACTIVITY A CODE

TextView username_tv;
String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    username_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_tv);

    //Get your username and store it in username
    username = getYourUsername();

    username_tv.setText(username);

    LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    lbm.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("USER_NAME_CHANGED_ACTION"));  
  }

  public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (intent != null) {
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        username_tv.setText(username);            
      }
  }
};

//ACTIVITY C CODE

//ADD this code to your 'SAVE' Button Listener
Intent intent = new Intent("USER_NAME_CHANGED_ACTION");
intent.putExtra("username", editText.getText().toString());
// put your all data using put extra 
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

For more information on localBroadcastManager look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager).

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you need this, but you can do it by saving the value of `EditText` in `ActivityC` in SparedPreferences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) is an example how can make it. Then you should check in `onResume()` method of `ActivityA`if there is saved value in SparedPreferences and if has some get the value and set it to "Username" `TextView`.

Comment: I have a same requirement in complex project, i need to save user location  at server side using api call and show updated data in ActivityA.

Answer (score 0):

EventBus will solve your problem
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Comment: event bus is good way but i dont know how to use of it can you please provide simple steps suggestion example, 


now i add this lib in my ptoject using this

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus